# Automatic information for Off-Topic/Low-Quality seeming questions

Tags: feature-request

I do not know if other SE-sites have the same amount of Off-Topic questions, but I sometimes get really frustrated browsing through the questions.

Just like the section "Questions that may already have your answer"- or the "Similar Questions"-section when asking a new question, this could greatly enhance the experience for new users.

Some ideas that could be checked:

- Question is too short, too little information provided
- Site-specific keywords defined by moderators, that show the asker why this question could be considered Off-Topic
- "Do-that-for-me" phrases
- other red flags

I do not want to restrict the question from being asked by a defined system. A question could of course appear Off-Topic but be valid instead.

One idea about that would be a checklist (much like when creating a password).

Of course, I know that all this is written in the FAQ, but we all know that especially new users do not always take the time to read those, resulting in higher administrative effort.

What are your thougts about that? Would it be possible to have something like that implemented?